# If $x,y$ are integers and $y>x>1$, then will it hold that $x^y > y^x$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

My friend and I hade a little discussion, where he claimed that if $x,y$ are integers, and $y>x>1$ then $x^y > y^x$

My friend has no proof, he says it logical, well is it?

Comment: Take $x=2,y=3$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true for $y>x>1$, but it is for $y>x>2$ because
the function $x \mapsto x^{1/x}$ has a single critical point at $x=e$ and is decreasing for $x \gt e$.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is wrong. For $x=2$ , $y=3$ you get : $2^3 > 3^2 \Leftrightarrow 8 > 9$ which is not true. Theoritically, you can prove the inequality by multivariable calculus, studying the function $F(x,y) = x^y - y^x$.

Comment: Multivariable calculus is too hard, I'd just study the single variable function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}x.$

Comment: You can do that too which is easier, but Multivariable Calculus is introduced in the first year for students of Mathematical universities, which is something elementary and a good practice too :)

Answer (score 1):

For positive $x$, $y$ we can take the natural logarithm of both sides and the order stays because the logarithm is strictly increasing:
$$
x^y > y^x \iff \\
y \ln(x) > x \ln(y)
$$
For positive $x, y$ this means we can divide and get
$$
f(x) := \frac{\ln(x)}{x} > \frac{\ln(y)}{y} = f(y)
$$
So the initial relation for $x < y$  holds for strictly decreasing $f$.

We have
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1 - \ln(x)}{x^2}
$$
which turns negative for $x>e$.